# How to get a subset of a list base on a starting and a ending character Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

From an existing list I want to be able to get all elements between a starting and ending point in a new list or a dictionary without using indexation. Since the number of elements will not always be the same I would like to be able to use 06 and 1c as start and end point.
all examples I have seen involve spliting strings by index

```
my_list = [
    '06',
    '1d',
    'job=123',
    'var2=213',
    'var3=2312',
    'var4=23124',
    'var5=21453415',
    '1c',

    '06',
    '1d',
    'job=234',
    'var2=213',
    'var3=2312',
    '1c',

    '06',
    '1d',
    'job=345',
    'var2=213',
    'var3=2312',
    'var4=23124',
    'var5=21453415',
    'var6=21453415',
    '1c',

    ]
# THIS WOULD BE COOL
new_list = [

    ['06', '1d', 'job=123', 'var2=213', 'var3=2312', 'var4=23124',  'var5=21453415', '1c'], 
    ['06', '1d', 'job=234', 'var2=213', 'var3=2312', '1c'],
    ['06', '1d', 'job=345', 'var2=213', 'var3=2312', 'var4=23124', 'var5=21453415', 'var6=21453415', '1c']

    ]
# THIS WOULD BE BEST
my_dict = {
    'job=123' : ['06', '1d', 'job=123', 'var2=213', 'var3=2312', 'var4=23124',  'var5=21453415'],
    'job=234' : ['06', '1d', 'job=234', 'var2=213', 'var3=2312', '1c'],
    'job=345' : ['06', '1d', 'job=345', 'var2=213', 'var3=2312', 'var4=23124', 'var5=21453415', 'var6=21453415', '1c']
}
```

Comment: Your list is invalid (the quotes are missing). Please add them where they belong. Otherwise, we cannot copy the list and would have to retype it. Also, what did you try? Please post your code. (Remember, SO is not a code writing service.)

Comment: @DYZ Will do! thanks

Comment: I havent tryed any code yet since I' only strating to investigate this  and I don't actualy want the code just an "explination"  or a sugestion on  how  can I achieve this.

Comment: The first row of `new_list` does not have `'1c'` at the end - is this intentional?

Comment: No it was accidental I'll add it.

Answer (score 1):

Start by finding the locations of the "start points" and "end points" of each row:

```
starts = [i for i, x in enumerate(my_list) if x =='06']
ends   = [i for i, x in enumerate(my_list) if x =='1c']
```

Now, select slices from the original list that start at a start point and end at the matching end point (inclusive):

```
[my_list[start:end+1] for start,end in zip(starts, ends)]
#[['06', '1d', 'job=123', 'var2=213', 'var3=2312', 'var4=23124', ..., '1c'], 
# ['06', '1d', 'job=234', 'var2=213', 'var3=2312', '1c'], 
# ['06', '1d', 'job=345', 'var2=213', 'var3=2312', ..., '1c']]
```

In fact, there is no need to include `'1c'`s in the original list unless there are gaps between the rows.

Comment: Is there a name for this procedure that I can look up to better comprehend what  its going on in this ?

Comment: It's called python programming.

Comment: Ok , as a beginner  i only know of the traditional  " for i in var : " loop  this  " i for i , x ... " have no clue on whats going on or how it works

Comment: I see. The construct is called list comprehension, and it allows to write a simple for loop on one line.